# how could I disable multi-selection in firefox?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox,if I hold the `ctrl` key and then I can perform a multi-selection on the web page.How could I disable this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Javascript `selectionchange` event to notice when the selection changes and then manually remove the selection ranges you don't like.

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function()
{
  var oSel = window.getSelection();
  if (oSel.rangeCount > 1)
  {
    var oFirstRange = oSel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    oSel.removeAllRanges();
    oSel.addRange(oFirstRange);
  }
});
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1hkestz/1/).

Comment: thanks very much,but how to disable it by config the browser instead of adding some code in the web?